# _additionalEmailAttribute1 in _Send database

Tags: marketing-cloud

Is there a way to run queries on the additional email attributes. Maybe include them in _Send table or in SendLogging.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but you'll have to set an AMPScript variable for it in every email:

```
%%[
var @AdditionalEmailAttribute1 
set @AdditionalEmailAttribute1 = AttributeValue("_additionalEmailAttribute1")
]%%
```

Then in your SendLog DE, if you add a `AdditionalEmailAttribute1` column, it'll get recorded for every send.

If you don't want to touch every email (and you're using headers and footers), you can include it in the account headers and footers in the `Admin > Account Settings`.